# a word for an unfamiliar situation

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a single word for an unfamiliar situation or a better way of wording this? 
If a situation is unfamiliar to you.

Comment: *This is all **new** to me.*

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 2):

Strange, Foreign, or Unknown?

Any of the synonyms for [unfamiliar](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfamiliar) may work:

> unfamiliar
>
> adjective
>
> 1. strange, new, unknown, different, novel, unusual, curious, alien, out-of-the-way, uncommon, little known, unaccustomed, beyond your ken

Answer (score 1):

try these:

imbroglio - intricate or complicated situation

quandary - A difficult situation.

You could also say you're in a cliffhanger (A story or event with a strong element of suspense).

Or you could combine several synonyms for strange, such as selcouth, with situation to get a "selcouth situation."

Answer (score 0):

Also consider synonyms of  *[enigma](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enigma#Noun)* (“Something puzzling, mysterious or inexplicable”), such as  *[conundrum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conundrum#Noun)* (“A difficult question or riddle”) and  *[mystery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mystery#Noun)* (“Someone or something with an obscure or puzzling nature”).